# Closing the previous activities in android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to close all the previous activities by pressing the logout button in android? I tried for intent flag clear top and android no history but both not works, please provide me some solutions. I am using android 2.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you have to clear each activity from  stack using

```
     youractivityname.this.finish();
```